# Rollapply for row in R with exp function

Tags: r, dataframe, rollapply

I have the data frame `df(A)` with 14 col and 1356 row. 
I have this function, for to apply a sum for every 12 row, like a moving average:

```
rollapply(A,width=12, FUN= sum,by.column=T)
```

But inside every 12 row i need to apply a multiplication for `exp(n/12)`, where `n`  are numbers from 0 to 11.
In synthesis the results could be:

```
rollapply(A,FUN=1°row *exp(0/12)+2°row*exp(2/12)....+12°row*exp(11/12),by.column=T)
```

Logically every 12 row the operation is repeated. Is possible apply this with function `rollapply`or i need to write a loop `for`?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update your function:

```
n = 12
rollapply(A, width=n, FUN=function(x) sum(x*exp((seq(n)-1)/n)))
```